# How do I authorize only my own mobile apps to call my rails 4 api?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, rails-api, http-token-authentication

I have a web app that exposes an api using devise_token_auth. I build multiple mobile apps that talk to different facets of this web app over https. They use devise_token_auth to get an access token, and then the access token is used in future requests.

I want to avoid the case where others create their own mobile apps that talk to my web backend.

When a call is made from the mobile client, it uses a user and password who has already signed up on my server to get an access token. How do I preclude others from creating their own mobile clients?

Option 1: I could create a secret api token, and use it on the client and server, where mobile client passes in the api token and the server only accepts the requests containing the api token. 
Problem with option 1: anyone who sees the request on the wire can now create a similar request with the api token, and use the api token to make the same call.

Option 2: I make my web server an oauth server, where my app uses oauth to authorize client requests only for my own api user, and rejects other requests.
Problem with option 2: I don't know enough about oauth to know if it works this way, and how to implement this in addition to devise_token_auth - this effectively means two credentials are checked on the server - the oauth verification of the api user, and the devise_token_auth verification of the actual user.

I did look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21465559/restrict-api-requests-to-only-my-own-mobile-app) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789685/creating-an-api-only-for-my-own-mobile-apps-do-i-need-oauth) related questions, but they are not exactly my scenario. The recommendation in those threads seems to be a) that https + basic auth is enough and oauth is unnecessary, and b) blocking ip addresses that are unauthorized (Problem: I don't know how to detect which ip address is my mobile app users' and which is someone else's). c) Another insight from those threads is that if I stored some private secret key in my mobile apps to use to identify the app, they are likely going to be exposed since mobile apps (at least on android) are fully reverse-engineerable.

Any suggestions on how best to design/implement this? Is just https + basic auth sufficient?

I would be happy to share any code (since SO usually expects code in the question) - but honestly don't know what code to share here.